# Difference of hotspot versus hot spot

Tags: orthography, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

hot spot  -vs-   hotspot

What's the difference between these two variants? When do I use them? An example sentence is as follows:

"Biochar addition is becoming one of the hotspots in soil science."

Here, "hotspots" is used as "a place of more than usual interest, activity, or popularity" ~Merriam. But, in the said dictionary, it is presented as two words, hot spot. So there, help me.

Comment: A "hot spot" is a spot that's hot.  A "hotspot" is a location of some intense activity.  And a "Hotspot" is a Java interpreter.

Comment: @HotLicks I mean, scientifically (a place of instense activity), i can use any of these two, right? Provided that i present it consistently?

Comment: Maybe if you described the context??

Comment: @HotLicks done bro

Comment: In your example, it seems like you are not referring to a physical location. If you are referring to a popular field of study, then "hot *topic*" would fit better.

Comment: @JJMDriessen Yes, you have got a point. But, these terms are often used  by many authors interchangeably. I wanna know the correct presentation, if there is any, for future uses.

Comment: My definition "location of intense activity" fits your example.

Comment: There is almost never any real difference between noun compounds with and without a space.

Answer (score 1):

When I see *hotspot* I think WIFI.  So, I recommend that you use *hot spot* for other things.

For the biochar -- please, definitely use *hot topics*, not *hotspots* or event *hot spots*.

Comment: Ok, appreciate it bro..

Comment: Fair enough but you're supposed to give evidence/references.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at the moment both are acceptable.

Some dictionaries say it is still two words "hot spot" and others say in all circumstances it should be written as one word: "hotspot".

Originally, it was always two words and it may be a good idea to still use it that way. Most dictionaries I use (LibreOffice, Google Office, Coda, browsers...) do not recognize "hotspot".

So either way is fine, the main idea is to use one spelling or the other consistently in your document.

Source: [Hot spot or hotspot](https://grammarist.com/usage/hot-spot-or-hotspot/)